# On line #64 of the code below, the "this" object is reference to what name object?

Tags: javascript

When executing this javascript code, line #64 (alert message) returns false, can someone tell me the name of the object that is invoking the GetOrMakeDom function from the point of line of code on 64? However the win object is not reference to the this object on line #64. Any idea which name object is reference to the this object on line $64

```js
/*dom - v0.1.0 - 2012-11-15
 * http://http://domenlightenment.com/#12
 * Copyright (c) 2012 Cody Lindley; Licensed MIT */

(function(win) {

  var global = win;
  var doc = global.document;

  var dom = function(params, context) {
    return new GetOrMakeDom(params, context);
  };

  var GetOrMakeDom = function(params, context) {

    var currentContext = doc;
    if (context) {
      if (context.nodeType) { //its either a document node or element node
        currentContext = context;
      } else { //else its a string selector, use it to selector a node
        currentContext = doc.querySelector(context);
      }
    }

    //if no params, return empty dom() object
    if (!params || params === '' || typeof params === 'string' && params.trim() === '') {
      this.length = 0;
      return this;
    }

    //if HTML string, construct domfragment, fill object, then return object
    if (typeof params === 'string' && /^\s*<(\w+|!)[^>]*>/.test(params)) { //yup its forsure html string
      //create div & docfrag, append div to docfrag, then set its div's innerHTML to the string, then get first child
      var divElm = currentContext.createElement('div');
      divElm.className = 'doc-frag-wrapper';
      var docFrag = currentContext.createDocumentFragment();
      docFrag.appendChild(divElm);
      var queryDiv = docFrag.querySelector('div');
      queryDiv.innerHTML = params;
      var numberOfChildren = queryDiv.children.length;
      //loop over nodelist and fill object, needs to be done because a string of html can be passed with siblings
      for (var z = 0; z < numberOfChildren; z++) {
        this[z] = queryDiv.children[z];
      }
      //give the object a length value
      this.length = numberOfChildren;
      //return object
      return this; //return e.g. {0:ELEMENT_NODE,1:ELEMENT_NODE,length:2}
    }

    //if a single node reference is passed, fill object, return object
    if (typeof params === 'object' && params.nodeName) {
      this.length = 1;
      this[0] = params;
      return this;
    }

    //if its an object but not a node assume nodelist or array, else its a string selector, so create nodelist
    var nodes;
    if (typeof params !== 'string') { //nodelist or array
      nodes = params;
    } else { //ok string
      nodes = currentContext.querySelectorAll(params.trim());
      alert(this === win);
    }
    //loop over array or nodelist created above and fill object
    var nodeLength = nodes.length;
    for (var i = 0; i < nodeLength; i++) {
      this[i] = nodes[i];
    }
    //give the object a length value
    this.length = nodeLength;
    //return  object
    return this; //return e.g. {0:ELEMENT_NODE,1:ELEMENT_NODE,length:2}

  };

  //expose dom to global scope
  global.dom = dom;

  //global short cut to prototype
  dom.fn = GetOrMakeDom.prototype;

})(window);


dom.fn.each = function(callback) {
  var len = this.length;
  for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    callback.call(this[i], i, this[i]);
  }
  return this;
};

dom.fn.html = function(htmlStringOrTextString) {
  if (htmlStringOrTextString) {
    return this.each(function() {
      this.innerHTML = htmlStringOrTextString;
    });
  } else {
    return this[0].innerHTML;
  }
};

dom.fn.text = function(textString) {
  if (textString) {
    return this.each(function() {
      this.textContent = textString;
    });
  } else {
    return this[0].textContent.trim();
  }
};

dom.fn.append = function(stringOrObject) {
  return this.each(function() {
    if (typeof stringOrObject === 'string') {
      this.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', stringOrObject);
    } else {
      var that = this;
      dom(stringOrObject).each(function(name, value) {
        that.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', value.outerHTML);
      });
    }
  });
};

dom("ul").append("<li>4</li>")
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<body>
  <ul>
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>3</li>
  </ul>
  <script src="https://raw.github.com/codylindley/domjs/master/builds/dom.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: it'd be the current instance of `GetOrMakeDom` class

Comment: Does `console.log(this);` reveal anything useful?

Comment: Looks like it is for debugging wither or not `GetOrMakeDom` was called with the `new` operator. It would be true if it was not as `this` would be the global `window`

Comment: @Patrick, are you saying "this" is equal window? I tried it and "this" does not equal window.

Comment: @Xufox, console.log(this), nothing useful

Comment: No, I am saying it would be equal to `window` if the call to `GetOrMakeDom` didnt use a `new` operator like it does further up in the code `new GetOrMakeDom(params, context)`.  which is called in`dom()` which is called at the end of your script `dom("ul")`